# Finding n Largest values of columns in a row VBA

Tags: vba

If you want to find the largest value in excel you can use the LARGE function. If you record the macro using the large function you get the following:

```
Sub test()
Range("L5").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=LARGE(RC[-1]:R[4]C[-1],1)"
Range("L5").Select
end
```

However, I want to find the n largest values and not just the largest value. I don't want to hardcode everything if n is large so I have tried with the following

```
sub test2()
For i = 1 To 6
Range("Li").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=LARGE(RC[-1]:R[4]C[-1], i)"
Next i
end
```

Not surprisingly

```
Range("Li").Select
```

is an error. What I am more interested in is

`"=LARGE(RC[-1]:R[4]C[-1], i)".`

Whenever I use "i" instead of an integer it gives me an error since in the excel worksheet it just returns #NAME.

So I am looking for a way to loop through "i" in the LARGE function witout getting the #NAME symbol in the corresponding workingsheet, but instead get the 1st largest number, 2nd largest number and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Move your `i` out of your text qualifying quotes in both cases.

Try this

```
sub test2()
For i = 1 To 6
Range("L" & i).Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = ("=LARGE(RC[-1]:R[4]C[-1]," & i & ")")
Next i
end
```

Answer (score 0):

The i shouldn't be within the quotes.

```
Sub test2()
Dim i As Long
    For i = 1 To 6
        Range("L" & i).FormulaR1C1 = "=LARGE(RC[-1]:R[4]C[-1], " & i & ")"
    Next i
End Sub
```